# Adding products to separate stores on magmi/magento

Tags: magento, magmi

I'm having difficulity creating a CSV file that import multiple products into different substores on Magmi. (Running Magmi v0.7.18beta2 and Magento ver. 1.7.0.2)

Based on what we've found elsewhere online, this is our headers on our csv with the text we've been using beside it

**sku** `TEST`

**store** `ourwebsite_en`

**websites** `ourwebsite.co.uk`

**categories** `Furniture`

**type** `simple`

**attribute set** `Furniture`

However each time the product is only added to the main root store, rather than our sub stores. Been experimenting with different names, but they are the only store names that magmi accepts on the csv and which match up with our manage stores page.

Any ideas how to fix this? All of our products are added into our root/base site by default, and we can't see a way to only add to our substores. We've tried creating new products to test, and overwriting old ones and each time they only go into our main store, and not the other stores we have under the 'store' column

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the [On the Fly category creator/importer](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer) plugin enabled in Magmi.

1. Create 2 **root** categories in Magento for each store view.
2. Assign the root categories to their respective stores `System > Manage Stores > *click store view name*`
3. Make sure your **Store View Code** is lowercase, no spaces (underscores).
4. Make sure your **Website Code** is lowercase, no spaces.

In your CSV datasource file, make sure you are setting the correct data.

1. **store** column should be the Magento **store code**
2. **websites** column should be the Magento **website code**
3. **sku** must be a unique value for each product
4. **attribute_set** must be an existing attribute set, already created in Magento.
5. For **categories**, put the **root category name** in brackets.  The format should be this:

   `[Root Category NAME For Store 1]/Furniture`

   `[Root Category NAME For Store 2]/Furniture`

   (swap out "Root Category NAME for Store 2 with that actual category root name for the store)

Comment: like why is this not on magmi documentation? here I was using the store **NAME** value, rather than the **CODE** value. This is not information you can intuit. This is stuff that needs to be documented.

Thanks x1000